# ofstream, when will it fail instead of creating a new file?

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

i just started reading on how to open and edit files.
when working with ifstream, if the file doesnt exist, it wont be created.

in reference to the code below, when would the condition (!outfile) be false, as if the file doesn't exists it will simply be created by the constructor, hence always making the condition false.

```
int main() 
{
    ofstream outfile ("test1.txt");

    if (!outfile) 
    {
        cout << "cannot create file test1.txt" << endl; 
        return 1;
    }
    outfile << 10 << " " << 345.12 << endl;
    outfile << "This is a short text file";
    outfile.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the user tuning the program doesn't have permission to create a file in the current working directory.

Comment: Thank you very much, never would have thought of that!

Comment: Path doesn't exist. Path+filename is too long. Permissions don't allow writing a file. Disk is full (either of data or no inodes available or equivalent). Invalid characters in the filename. No filename. The computer is on fire. Any of these might cause it to fail and I'm sure I missed some.

Answer (score 1):

One way opening an `ofstream` could fail is if the file in the given path exists, but you do not have the permission to write to it. Alternatively, if the file does not exist but you do not have permission to create a file in the given path, opening the `ofstream` should also fail.

Another failing situation could be if the files does not exist, and the underlying device does not have sufficient free space/inodes to create one.